# Swifty JSON UITableView background error

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swifty-json

I've followed the tutorial from [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial). However I'm not getting the array direct into the UITableView. It takes now about 20 seconds to load the JSON into the UITableView. But in the Console log the Array is direct available. I'm working in Swift 2.0.

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

let textCellIdentifier = "CoffeeLocations"
var apps : [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    DataManager.getTopAppsDataFromItunesWithSuccess { (iTunesData) -> Void in
        let json = JSON(data: iTunesData)

        if let appArray = json[].array {

            for appDict in appArray {
                let appName: String? = appDict["name"].string
                self.apps += ["\(appName!)"]
            }

            print(self.apps) // Here he print directly to the console log
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return apps.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.titleLabel!.text = apps[row]
    //cell.detailLabel!.text = description[row] Later I want to add a second rule
    return cell
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Error log (directly):

> 2015-09-24 09:45:31.493 TopApps[660:180190] **Received memory warning.**
>   **["\'t Koffiehuisje", "Caffee Allee | Stadsrestaurant", "Ketelhuis", "Monk Eindhoven", "Radio Royaal", "PopEi Food & Drinks", "Tijdelijk restaurant", "NATLAB", "Bagel & Juice", "Pastry club", "Intellegentia ICE", "Onder de leidingstraat", "Keukenconfessies"]**

Error log for every line in the array (after 20 seconds):

> 2015-09-24 09:46:09.579 TopApps[660:180231] **This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.**
>    Stack:(
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182bb0f74  + 148
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001977a3f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182bb0ea4  + 0
>       3   Foundation                          0x0000000183bca5d8  + 88
>       4   Foundation                          0x0000000183a4ca1c  + 36
>       5   UIKit                               0x000000018820b958  + 64
>       6   UIKit                               0x00000001881022d8  + 240
>       7   UIKit                               0x0000000188101b8c  + 116
>       8   UIKit                               0x0000000188101a18  + 504
>       9   UIKit                               0x00000001884098e0  + 228
>       10  UIKit                               0x0000000188100458  + 412
>       11  UIKit                               0x00000001881fae14  + 1440
>       12  UIKit                               0x00000001881efab8  + 216
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000018810300c  + 644
>       14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187909f14  + 148
>       15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187904b20  + 292
>       16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001879049e0  + 32
>       17  QuartzCore                          0x000000018790407c  + 252
>       18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187903dd0  + 516
>       19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187932f48  + 236
>       20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001981b21e8  + 584
>       21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001981b1d60  + 136
>       22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001981b1544 pthread_mutex_lock + 0
>       23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001981b1028 start_wqthread + 4
>   )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    // put your code here  load the JSON into the UITableView
})
```